# How to assign yAxisID to ChartJs datapoint

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I have following dataset:

```
[
    {data: [100, 50, 0.5], backgroundColor:'#506f86', borderColor: '#506f86', hoverBackgroundColor:'#384e5e', hoverBorderColor: '#384e5e', label: 'Service'},
    {data: [80, 20, 0.25], backgroundColor:'#9ec5fe', borderColor: '#9ec5fe', hoverBackgroundColor:'#6ea8fe', hoverBorderColor: '#6ea8fe', label: 'Maintenance'},
    {data: [60, 20, 0.33], backgroundColor:'#ffc107', borderColor: '#ffc107', hoverBackgroundColor:'#cc9a06', hoverBorderColor: '#cc9a06', label: 'Monitoring'}
]
```

Here, datapoints are as follows:

```
data[0] - Sales
data[1] - Gross Profit $
data[2] - Gross Profit %
```

I have following scales defined:

```
scales: {
      dollar: {
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            callback: (label, index, labels) => {
              return `$ ${label}`;
            }
          }
      },
      percent: {
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'right',
          grid: {
              display: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            color: '#de703c',
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return (value + '%');
            }
          }
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          axis: 'x',
          labels: ['Sales', 'Gross Profit $', 'Gross Profit %'],
      },
    },
```

[This is what the chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbDzm.png)

I would like the third datapoint "Gross Profit %" in the dataset to be mapped to yAxisID "percent" on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the values for the Gross Profit % are not working as the values are too small for the y-axis (dollar) compared to other values.

The proposed *hack way* is by showing the percentage value as a whole number (rate * maxValue) instead of a decimal (0.25).

Formula:

```
rate = x / maxValue
x = rate * maxValue
```

The implementation will be:

1. Record the data index for Gross Profit % which is 2. Also get the max value for the dataset.

```
grossProfitPctBarIndex = 2;
// Or
// this.grossProfitPctBarIndex = this.barChartLabels.length - 1;

this.maxValue = this.barChartData
      .map((x) => x.data)
      .reduce((acc: number[], cur: number[]) => {
        acc = acc.concat(...cur);

        return acc;
      }, [])
      .sort((a: number, b: number) => b - a)[0];
```

2. The values for the data index for Gross Profit % to be multiplied by `maxValue`.

```
ratioToValue(ratio: number) {
  return ratio * this.maxValue;
}
```

```
this.barChartData.forEach((x) => {
  x.data[this.grossProfitPctBarIndex] = this.ratioToValue(
        x.data[this.grossProfitPctBarIndex]
      );
});
```

3. For the tooltip, you should override the [tooltip callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) to show the bar value for Gross Profit % in decimal (0.25) instead of the whole number.

```
valuetoRatio(value: number) {
  return value / this.maxValue;
}
```

```
barChartOptions = {
  ...,
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (context: any) => {
          let label = context.dataset.label || '';

          if (label) {
            label += ': ';
          }

          if (context.dataIndex == this.grossProfitPctBarIndex) {
            if (context.parsed.y !== null) label += this.valuetoRatio(context.parsed.y);
          } else {
             label += context.parsed.y;
          }

          return label;
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

4. For the onclick event, you should implement the same concept in (3) to show the value in decimal for Gross Profit %.

```
barChartOptions = {
  ...,
  onClick: (evt: any, elements: any, chart: any) => {
    const bars = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(
      evt,
      'nearest',
      { intersect: true },
      true
    );
    if (bars.length === 0) return; // no bars

    const bar = bars[0];

    // Get index and label text

    const index = bar.index;
    const label = chart.data.labels[index];
    let selectedDataset = chart.data.datasets[bar.datasetIndex];

    console.log('Selected label:', label);
    console.log('Selected sub-label:', selectedDataset.label);
    console.log(
      "Selected sub-label's value:",
      bar.index == this.grossProfitPctBarIndex
        ? this.valuetoRatio(selectedDataset.data[index])
        : selectedDataset.data[index]
    );
  },
};
```

Note that you need to migrate the `onClick` function from the normal function to the arrow function in order to allow passing the `grossProfitPctBarIndex`. You may refer to [Arrow functions do not create their own this binding](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-difference-between-arrow-functions-and-normal-functions/).

> Result

[image]

[Demo @ Stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-etpphu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun. I have implemented something similar to what you mentioned here. The issue is, in actual dataset the Sales amount are in thousands & millions so the chart doesn't render Gross Profit % as nicely or even visible. My workaround is to get the max value of "dollar" scale, multiply Gross Profit % by that and customize the tooltip lable to show actual percentage and define the min-max value for "percent scale" accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback, ya, shouldn't multiply by 100. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.